# Make/force Scrapy to use Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, package

On my system, I've both python3 and python 2.7, scrapy only suports python2.7 but by debault my libraries are linked to python 3.4.

I am trying to run a basic example that comes with scrapy documentation that is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import scrapy



class StackOverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stackoverflow'
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('.question-summary h3 a::attr(href)'):
            full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.css('h1 a::text').extract()[0],
            'votes': response.css('.question .vote-count-post::text').extract()[0],
            'body': response.css('.question .post-text').extract()[0],
            'tags': response.css('.question .post-tag::text').extract(),
            'link': response.url,
        }
```

To run this code, is suggested for the command:

`scrapy runspider stackoverflow_spider.py -o top-stackoverflow-questions.json`

being *stackoverflow_spider.py* the above snippet.

The problem is that somehow this is calling python3,and since I am not explicitly calling a python version, not sure how to **force** the command to use python2.7 libs.

below is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Scrapy==1.0.5', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 122, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 21, in _iter_command_classes
    for obj in vars(module).itervalues():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'
```

PS: I have installed *scrapy* under python 2.7

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893069/how-to-create-the-scrapy-project-by-python3.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks, `pip install scrapy==1.1.0rc1` was the part I was missing! Working now!